# How to show node labels as shown in pst-optexp documentation?

Tags: pstricks, pst-optexp

In the [pst-optexp documentation](http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-optexp/pst-optexp.pdf), they show this example:

[image: A working example of the node labels]

When I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0, -.3)(3,3.3)
\pnode(0,2.5){A}\pnode(2,2.5){B}\pnode(2,1.5){C}%
\mirror[labelangle=-45](A)(B)(C){M}
\optbox[position=start, labeloffset=0,labelref=relative](C)(B){box}
\drawbeam(A){1}{2}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I get this:

[image: My implementation of the code, where the gray node labels are missing]

How can I reproduce the gray node labels they have in their diagram?

Comment: I use the `LTXexample` for the code examples in the documentation. Some lines are skipped with `linerange` because they only serve for highlighting some aspects of the example but are irrelevant for the actual package usage. Search for `LTXexample` at https://github.com/cbersch/pst-optexp/blob/master/pst-optexp.dtx to find all examples, or https://github.com/cbersch/pst-optexp/tree/master/tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are. I completed the code. Note it works with `pdflatex`, thanks to the `auto-pst-pdf` package, if you add the `--enable-write18` switch under MiKTeX, `-shell-escape` under TeX Live or MacTeX.

It also compile via `latex->dvips->pstopdf`, but remove `auto-pst-pdf`.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt, svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-0.3)(3,3.3)
\pnodes(0,2.5){A}(2,2.5){B}(2,1.5){C}
\mirror[labelangle=-45](A)(B)(C){M}
\optbox[position=start, labeloffset=0, labelref=relative](C)(B){box}
\drawbeam(A){1}{2}
\psdots[linecolor=Gainsboro](A)(B)(C)
\everypsbox{\color{Silver}}
\nput{90}{A}{A}
\nput{-135}{B}{B}
\nput{50}{C}{C}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]